# Is there a Windows cmd line script to add dummy labels to missing taxonomic levels in a 16S bioinformatic fasta file?

Tags: windows, data

There is a common problem where taxonomic levels are are missing in 16S labels, and the convention is to fill in the missing levels with a generic place holder referencing the following lower label, but I'm new to the field and don't know where I would find a script like this.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: There are a lot science-related SE site, among these: https://stackexchange.com/sites I think some bioinformatics or "open data" would be useful if you don't get help here now.